# Upgrading mysql version to 5.6 for word press version 4.7.4

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, version

I am currently using word press 4.7.4 in my website and mysql version 5.1. I need to upgrade my mysql version to 5.6 . If any one faced the problem when upgrading and any deprecated functions?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you host your website?
if you host it online, then you've to contact your hosting provider?
if you use XAMPP or WAMPP, then download the latest version from the internet.